# How to add an existing non-Administrator to the Administrators group?

Tags: windows-7

A friend popped round their family laptop after discovering that his wife's user account fails to logon with the following error message (it's a Dell Inspiron N5050 running Windows 7 Home Premium Edition):

> The User Profile Service failed the logon

His wife's user account is the one created when Windows was first setup during the initial Dell OEM first-time Out of Box Experience. This account is a Windows administrator and is the only administrator. There is another account used by their son which does not have administrator rights.

I followed the steps that apply to this scenario described in this article to try to enable the regular Administrator account using `net user administrator password /active:yes`:

> [I receive error message: The user profile service failed the logon. User profile cannot be loaded](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-security/i-receive-error-message-the-user-profile-service/38844b82-a2c1-4fa2-9802-a5318d6f7831)

i.e. I've booted from the Windows installation disk, launched the recovery tools and started a command prompt. I then typed `net user administrator [some_password] /active:yes` which tells me the command ran successfully. However when I restart Windows (in safe mode or normally) I don't see an Administrator account at the logon screen.

I have to do this because for some reason I can't boot to a Safe Mode command prompt, Windows just boots straight to the logon screen.

As already mentioned there is another account on the machine but it's not a member of the Administrators group but I can logon. Using this account I have tried to `runas` a new command prompt as both Administrator and his wife's account but get an error message saying that the username or password are invalid.

I think something has clobbered his Wife's user account because when I navigate the filesystem using the recovery console command prompt I don't see this account's folder in the user profile folder but do see one for the other non-administrator account.

I've also tried to restore to a previous system recover point (via booting from the Windows DVD and starting the recovery tools). There was in fact one created on the morning that this problem manifested itself after a Windows Update. However after around 10 or so minutes of telling me it was *Finalizing the Restore* I was then presented with an error dialogue stating that:

> System Restore did not complete successfully. Your computer's system files and settings were not changed.
>
> Details:
>
> An unspecified error occurred during System Restore (0x80070002).

I also tried an earlier one but end up with the same result.

I've also tried creating a new Windows account in the command prompt launched by the recovery tools but I can't add that user to the Administrators group because the Workstation service isn't running (and won't start in recovery mode).

Is there anything else I can try or am I going to have to flatten rebuild this machine? Is there any other way for me to elevate the existing non-Administrator account to become a member of the Administrators group?

Comment: Have you tried running a `sfc /scannow` or a `chkdsk`? With multiple errors like that, it sounds like something is missing/corrupted.

Comment: @moses I did, no errors :/

Answer (score 1):

It's very easy to create a new administrator account by booting your computer from Hiren's Boot CD. This article [Using Hiren's Boot CD to Create Admin User Accounts](http://romesitguy.hubpages.com/hub/Using-Hirens-Boot-CD-to-Create-Admin-Accounts) details all the steps.

Comment: I had no idea that was still around. Will give it a go.

Comment: If you have problem of creating a new admin, you can choose to boot from PCUnlocker Boot CD and it can help you promote a standard user account to administrator.